# vb .net Regex query

Tags: regex, vb.net

I am trying to find phrases in a text file which are capitalized.

I have come up with a regex which captures a phrase like "New Lender":

```
(?:[A-Z][A-z]+(?:\x20+|\,|\.|\:|\;|\r|\n|\t|\x29|\x22|\x2D|\x26))+
```

but I am stumped about phrases like `"Bank of England"`. There are very few uncapitalized words which will come up `(of|and|or)`, but am struggling to get the regex to match beyond `"Bank of"`.  Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
(?:\b([A-Z]\w+)\b(?:\s|of|and|or)*)+
```

Comment: Thanks Kash, appreciate the prompt response.  The pattern is now catching "Bank of England" but also "Bank of the river".  Is it possible to amend the Regex so the word following the option is itself capitalized?